# how to position the infowindow just above the marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a map based application. I have given customized markers and on click of that marker an infowindow appears above that. My application is working fine but on click of the marker, the infowindow is appearing way too above the marker. How can I minimize that distance (distance between marker & infowindow) and position the infowindow just above the marker?
Note: I have not written any code as far as the problem is concerned regarding the positioning of the marker. Its coming way too above the marker by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Marker.setInfoWindowAnchor()` method (x and y offset is float and in marker width and height corresponding, e.g. (0; -2f) means above 2 height of marker). See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions) for details.